# How do I output name and value of a variable?

Tags: vbscript

I am new to VB Script and have a question, how do I assign a Name to the Variables I have input so that they display on the screen?
For example, Once I have input a name I would like the final information box to show the Name value as:

```
Name: <entered value>
```

I understand how to assign the 'entered value' but not the 'Name' itself..?

```
name=inputbox("What is your name?", "Personal Details")
address=inputbox("Please enter your Full Address inc. Post Code", "Address")
tele=inputbox("Please enter your telephone number", "Telephone Number")
msgbox name &vbLf&vbLf& address &vbLf&vbLf& tele, 1, "New Customer Details"
```

Comment: When you say "VB Script", what *specifically* do you mean?  VB.NET, VBA, or VBScript?  All three are different technologies, so being specific about which one you are using is helpful to everyone.

Comment: Looks like VBA to me... please specify

Comment: The issue has been resolved. I just wanted to know how to add names for data typed in such as Name and Address

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't very clear so it's quite possible I've misunderstood, but if you just want to know how to add in a static string to your output, then you just add it as `"Name: " &`. 
So combined with your code it would be something like:

`msgbox "Name: " &name &vbLf&vbLf& address &vbLf&vbLf& tele, 1, "New Customer Details"`

Comment: Hey 'Ho1' you are correct, thank you for your prompt and logical response, I did the following and now it is working:     

msgbox "Name:  " &name &vbLf&vbLf& "Address:  " &address &vbLf&vbLf& "Telephone Number:  " &tele, 1, ("New Customer Details")